# Using TikTok's Partner API and PHP, how do you create the signature to pass with API calls?

Tags: php, go, digital-signature, tiktok

Tiktok's API "signature" piece is a nightmare, and I can find absolutely no information from anywhere about it, other than their lame documentation linked below, where the example is written in "golang" - whatever the heck THAT is lol

I managed to put the encryption code together in two lines of PHP (see below), but the confusing part to me is Step 5 of these signing instructions where it talks about passing the body:

> "If the request header content_type is not multipart/form-data, append body to the end"

Body? What body?? From the cUrl request I haven't even made yet???  I am so lost on this step, but its necessary for GET requests apparently, and probably why my signature is always coming back as invalid from the API.

https://partner.tiktokshop.com/docv2/page/64f199709495ef0281851fd0

PHP code where `$input` is the concatenated string as per documentation, sans the illusive 'body' part from step 5.

```
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $input, $secretKey, true);
    $urlSafeEncoded = urlencode(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($hmac), '+/', '-_'), '='));
```

Hopefully someone out here has experience with this chaos and can understand what they mean by body.

**FOLLOW UP:**
using a Postman example in API docs, I can get the call to work. They provide snippets of Javascript and Golang code to create the signature in Postman.  I'd like to post their code, and my php code here for comparison in case anyone can see what I may be missing in my php code, please and thank you!

Javascript Signature Code (works!)

```
// Replace secret with your own  
var secret = "c4bb0b4d6ad7407cb53e6bc038a3074b15fc53b0"  
  
function objKeySort(obj) {  
    var newKey = Object.keys(obj).sort()  
    var newObj = {}  
    for (var i = 0; i < newKey.length; i++) {  
        newObj[newKey[i]] = obj[newKey[i]]  
    }  
    return newObj  
}  
  
function getEnvVar(k) {  
    var v = pm.variables.get(k)  
    if (v != null) {  
        return v  
    }  
    v = pm.environment.get(k)  
    if (v != null) {  
        return v  
    }  
    v = pm.globals.get(k)  
    if (v != null) {  
        return v  
    }  
    return null  
}  
  
var ts = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000  
pm.variables.set("timestamp", ts)  
  
calSign = function(secret) {  
    var ts = getEnvVar("timestamp")  
    var queryParam = pm.request.url.query.members  
    var param = {}  
    for (var item in queryParam) {  
        if (queryParam[item].key == "timestamp") {  
            v = ts  
        } else {  
            var v = queryParam[item].value  
            if (v == null || v == "{{" + queryParam[item].key + "}}") {  
                v = getEnvVar(queryParam[item].key)  
            }  
        }  
        param[queryParam[item].key] = v  
    }  
  
    delete param["sign"];  
    delete param["access_token"]  
    var sortedObj = objKeySort(param)  
    var signstring = secret + pm.request.url.getPath()  
    for (var key in sortedObj) {  
        signstring = signstring + key + sortedObj[key]  
    }  
    signstring = signstring + secret  
    sign = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signstring, secret).toString()  
    return sign  
}  
  
var sign = calSign(secret)  
pm.variables.set("sign", sign)
```

Golang Signature Code (works!)

```
import (  
   "crypto/hmac"  
   "crypto/sha256"  
   "encoding/hex"  
   "sort"  
)  
/**  
** path: API path, for example /api/orders  
** queries: Extract all query param EXCEPT 'sign','access_token',query param,not body  
** secret: App secter  
**/  
func generateSHA256(path string, queries map[string]string, secret string) string{  
     
   //Reorder the params based on alphabetical order.  
   keys := make([]string, len(queries))  
   idx := 0  
   for k, _ := range queries{  
      keys[idx] = k  
      idx++  
   }  
   sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool {  
      return keys[i] < keys[j]  
   })  
     
   //Concat all the param in the format of {key}{value} and append the request path to the beginning  
   input := path  
   for _, key := range keys{  
      input = input + key + queries[key]  
   }  
     
   //Wrap string generated in up with app_secret.  
   input = secret + input + secret  
  
   //Encode the digest byte stream in hexadecimal and use sha256 to generate sign with salt(secret)  
   h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret))  
     
   // error log  
   if _, err := h.Write([]byte(input)); err != nil{  
      // todo: log error  
      return ""  
   }  
  
   return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))  
}
```

PHP Code (does not work!)

```
    public function encrypt_sign($vars)
    {
      $qstring = '';
      ksort($vars['qvars']);
      if (count($vars['qvars']) > 0) {
        foreach ($vars['qvars'] as $k=>$v) {
          if ($k != 'sign') {
            $qstring .= $k.$v;
          }
        }
      }

      //add body of request here!?!  what body, its a get request!
      //$qstring = $qstring.{request body};

      $qstring = $this->tiktok_app_secret . $qstring . $this->tiktok_app_secret;

      $sign = $this->encryptForUrl($qstring, $this->tiktok_app_secret);
      
      return $sign;
    }

    public function encryptForUrl($input, $secretKey)
    {
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $input, $secretKey, true);

        $urlSafeEncoded = urlencode(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($hmac), '+/', '-_'), '='));

        return $urlSafeEncoded;
    }
```

Comment: GET requests don't usually have a body, so I don't think anything but leaving this part completely empty, would make any sense.

Comment: that's what I figured, but no matter what I try, all I can ever get back from this junk API is "signature is invalid".

Comment: What context are you using that token in, and how exactly? The replacing of `+/` with `-_` I am familiar with as "URL-safe Base64" in contexts where the value actually needs to be passed via URL, but I don't see it actually mentioning anything about it on that tiktok docu page.

Comment: Looks like the JS version doesn't even include Base64 encoding at all? `return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))` - that will return the binary value as a string of hex digits - that is something completely different, than base64 encoding.

Comment: I think you need `hash_hmac('sha256', $input, $secretKey, false);`, and that's it. No base64 encoding, no replacing of any characters to make anything "URL safe".

Comment: I saw some where in the API doc about base64 and url encoding it, but I will remove all that and try your suggestion.  I have tried removing it, but I never changed the 4th param of hash to false... could it be that simple?  lol   Let's see!! Stay tuned!!!

Comment: bummer, no difference without base64 or url encoding, and using the false param on hash function.  Darn it!  I just don't understand, and you'd think the API would say more than "invalid signature" :(   Anyone want to earn a few bucks?

Comment: Is there an `access_token` in your parameters, by any chance? The given JS code explicitly skips parameters `sign` and `access_token`, your PHP code only the former.

Comment: great observation skills... I only pass that function the necessary params, saves the step of removing them ;)   Its really not complex code, its driving me nuts because I know its going to be something silly like the wrong encoding on the signature.  Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original question only missing thing I saw was the "path". For example:  "/authorization/202309/shops"

Just incase if someone still looking for this, here is working function:

```
function signature($path, $params, $app_secret, $requet_method = 'GET', $requet_type = "normal", $body = '')
{
    $arr_params = [];
    if(!is_array($params))
    {
        parse_str($params, $arr_params);
    }
    ksort($arr_params);

    $input = '';
    foreach($arr_params as $key => $value)
    {
        $input .= $key . $value;
    }

    if ($requet_method !='GET' && $requet_type != 'multipart/form-data') {
        $input .= $body;
    }
    $input = $path . $input;

    $input = $app_secret . $input . $app_secret;
    
    return bin2hex(hash_hmac('sha256', $input, $app_secret, true));
}
```

Comment: oh great, thanks, I can't wait to test it out!  some APIs give me such a headache lol Much appreciated!